# Why should OutputStream be closed after inputstream in android

Tags: java, android, inputstream, outputstream

I am doing two succssive calls to my servlet from android in this way:

```
//FIRST CONNECTION
URL url = new URL("http://172.16.32.160:8080/xyz/check_availability");
            HttpURLConnection connection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            ObjectOutputStream out=new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            String a="xya";
            String b="xsw";
            out.writeObject(a);

            out.flush();


            ObjectInputStream in=new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            String s=(String)
            in.readObject();
            in.close();
            out.close();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            //SECOND CONNECTION 


            URL url1 = new URL("http://172.16.32.160:8080/xyz/check_availability");
            HttpURLConnection connection1 = (HttpURLConnection)url1.openConnection();
            connection1.setDoOutput(true);


            ObjectOutputStream out1=new ObjectOutputStream(connection1.getOutputStream());
            out1.writeObject(b);
            out1.flush();

            ObjectInputStream in1=new ObjectInputStream(connection1.getInputStream());
                String str=(String)
                in1.readObject();
                in1.close();
                out1.close();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The above code works well because I've closed the outputstream of the first connection after closing the inputstream. But If I close the outputstream after sending the object, the second input stream throws an exception:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException
```

Why should the outputstream be closed after closing the inputstream?
**NOTE**
    If someone knows the actual answer  or the proper reason as to why it does not work in Android,     please answer. Till then I will accept the answer given by EJP - that it is a bug in android.

Comment: The proper reason has already been given. 'Bug in Android'. Given the facts and given that it works in a JRE there is no other possible explanation.

Comment: @EJP : Yes it is a bug like you said. What I meant was what is the cause of this bug. I mean does android close the connection when outputstream is closed or something else happens.

Comment: "does android close the connection when outputstream is closed". Yes, apparently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a bug in Android to me.

In Java whence this comes, closing the `ObjectOutputStream` at any time over an `HttpURLConnection` does nothing except flush the output (because the connection has to stay up to receive the response). Closing the input stream of an `HttpURLConnection` closes the entire connection, so a subsequent close of the `ObjectOutputStream` would do nothing.

I suspect Android does something bad to the connection when you do the `ObjectOutputStream.close()` first, such as closing it.

I would omit the `ObjectOutputStream.close()` altogether, you don't need it in either platform. The `flush()` is sufficient.

Comment: Have you also experienced this in andriod?

Comment: @user1139023 I'm deducing it from the behaviour you reported and my knowledge of the Java(TM) platform.

Comment: You are right. Same code executed in java does not give any exception and works well.