# Java Android Sockets

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking

I'm currently working on an Android app which sends an string and a file to a java server app running on remote computer. This java server app should find the index on the file and send back the value of this index (The file structure is:  index value. Example:  1 blue) The file is properly sent and received on the remote machine and I have a method which finds the value of the received index on the file. But when I'm trying to send the found value back to the phone I get an exception (closed socket), but I'm not closing the socket or any buffer. I'm not sure if the socket which is closed is the mobile app socket or the java server app socket. I'm using the same socket I use to send to receive (which is the way to work on Android). Sending the answer back to the phone is what my project is missing and is what I need help in. Here is my code:

Client app (Android app):

```
 private class HeavyRemProcessing extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
        {

            protected String doInBackground(String... urls) 
             {
                    begins = System.currentTimeMillis();

                            remoteExecution();

                ends= System.currentTimeMillis();
                procTime=ends-begins;
                aux= Long.toString(procTime);

               return aux;
             } //doInBackground() ends

            protected void onPostExecute(String time)
              {
                textView1.setText("Result: "+result+". Processing Time: "+time+" milisecs"); 
              }// onPostExecute ends

        } //HeavyRemProcessing ends


     public void executor(View view)
      {     
         key="74FWEJ48DX4ZX8LQ";

         HeavyRemProcessing task = new HeavyRemProcessing();
         task.execute(new String[] { "????" });     
      } //executor() ends


     public void remoteExecution()
        {
               // I have fixed IP and port I just deleted 
           String ip;  //SERVER IP
           int port;   // SERVER PORT 

             try
               {
                 cliSock = new Socket(ip, port);

                 file= new File("/mnt/sdcard/download/Test.txt"); 

                 long length = file.length();
                 byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) length];

                 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                 BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                 BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(cliSock.getOutputStream());
                 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cliSock.getInputStream()));


                 int count;
                 key=key+"\r\n";
                 out.write(key.getBytes());
                 while ((count = bis.read(bytes)) > 0) 
                  {
                     out.write(bytes, 0, count);
                  }  //It works perfectly until here


                   //// PROBABLY HERE IS THE PROBLEM:               
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                fis.close();
                bis.close();                    

                result= in.readLine();  //RECEIVE A STRING FROM THE REMOTE PC


              }catch(IOException ioe)
                {
                 // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ioe.toString() +   ioe.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                } 

            }catch(Exception exp)
              {
                 //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),exp.toString() +   exp.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();               
              }   

        } //remoteExecution ends
```

Java Server App (Remote PC)

```
 public void receivingFile()
      {
         System.out.println("Executing Heavy Processing Thread (Port 8888).");

         try 
            {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);
                InputStream is = null;
                OutputStream os= null;
                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
                BufferedOutputStream boSock =null;
                DataOutputStream dataOutputStream=null;
                int bufferSize = 0;


                try 
                   {
                     socket = serverSocket.accept();  
                     System.out.println("Heavy Processing Task Connection from ip: " + socket.getInetAddress());

                   } catch (Exception ex) 
                     {
                       System.out.println("Can't accept client connection: "+ex);
                     }

                try 
                   {
                     is = socket.getInputStream();
                     dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                     bufferSize = socket.getReceiveBufferSize();

                   }
                     catch (IOException ex) 
                       {
                         System.out.println("Can't get socket input stream. ");
                       }

                try 
                   {
                     fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
                     bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

                   }
                     catch (FileNotFoundException ex) 
                      {
                        System.out.println("File not found. ");
                      }

                byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];

                int count;
                System.out.println("Receiving Transfer File!.");

                while ((count = is.read(bytes)) > 0) 
                  {
                     bos.write(bytes, 0, count);
                  }

                System.out.println("File Successfully Received!.");
                fos.close();
                bos.flush();
                bos.close();
                is.close();

                result= obj.searchIndex();
                System.out.println("Found: "+result); //This correctly print the found value

                dataOutputStream.writeUTF(result);
                dataOutputStream.flush();
                dataOutputStream.close();

                System.out.println("Data sent back to the Android Client. ");


           } catch (IOException e) 
              {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
              }

      } // receivingFile() ends
```

Please if someone can help me I will really appreciate it. I'm thinking is something probably related with the buffers and the socket. My java server app throws an exception: "Closed Socket"... Thanks for your time,

Alberto.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you closing the `outputstream` before closing the `inputstream`. This is a bug in android. Normally in java closing `outputstream` only  **flushes** the data and closing **inputstream** causes the connection to be closed.
 But in android closing the `outputstream` closes the connection. That is why you are getting closed socket exception,
Put the statements

```
out.flush();
 out.close();
```

after

```
result=in.readLine();
```

or just avoid those statements(out.flush and out.close). I had also faced a similar problem. See my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701872/why-should-outputstream-be-closed-after-inputstream-in-android)

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your quick answer, you meant on the server application or on the Android client?  Thanks again

Comment: @user1186061 : In android. It is a bug in android.

Comment: Hi, Ahawin, Tahnks for your help, I really appreciate it. I modified my code, but now on the server side the app looks like the file transfer has not finished even when the file is completed, because of it, the server app doesn't do anything else and it gets stuck on receiving the file from the Android. I flushed it, I eliminated the code for closing the buffers and socket but it still does not work, do you have any other suggestion? or way to solve it? Thanks a lot:     fis.close();
       bis.close(); 
              
       result= in.readUTF();
     
       out.flush();
       out.close();

Comment: remember I'm seding a file and I also have file buffers, I close them after the transmission, but I don't clase the outputstream or the socket until I try to get the inputstream from the socket. while ((count = bis.read(bytes)) > 0) 
         {
            out.write(bytes, 0, count);
         }
        
       fis.close();
       bis.close(); 
      // out.flush();
       
       result= in.readUTF();
     
       in.close();
       out.close();

Comment: I tried using the out.flush(); but it didn't work so I just commented it.

Comment: @user1186061 : In your android code, place the lines - "out.flush();
                out.close();
                fis.close();
                bis.close();" AFTER "result= in.readLine();". Did you do this?

Comment: Yes, I did it. but on the server side it gets stuck "receiving the file" and I check the file size after couple seconds and it's of the size it should be. When I close the socket it receives the file and it does a search on the file, but when I want to return the result of the search it gives me the "closed socket exception". So, if I don't close the socket on the Android app, the server app "thinks" is still receiving the file. If I close the socket it shows me an "closed socket" exception... This is driving me crazy!.. Any other suggestion Ashwin? Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: @user1186061 : I think I got the problem. In server side code, close the input stream after output stream i.e opp of android. Place the line "is.close();" AFTER " dataOutputStream.writeUTF(result);
                dataOutputStream.flush();
                dataOutputStream.close();". Hope this works.

Comment: Hey man, Thanks for your help. I didn't work I have no idea what's going wrong. I really appreciate your time man...

Comment: @user1186061 : no problem dude. I think you must have already tried this, but did you make both the changes and try i.e in both android and java?

Comment: Yes I did it. I've been stuck on this couple days and I have been able to fix it, this is frustrating... Everything looks to be ok, but as I told you, the only way to receive the file and the server app star doing the search on the file is when I close the socket on the Android app after transmitting the file.. :s I don't know what else to try!..

Comment: Thanks for asking man. No, I haven't been able to fix it yet.Do you any suggestion? Thanks for keeping in touch man, I appreciate it.

Comment: @user1186061 : I had the same problem. It got rectified when I closed the outputstream after inputstream. But here, something else seems to be the problem. Sorry, I have no suggestion. But tell me if you get the answer.

Comment: @user1186061 : Why don't you earn more points(77) and start a bounty. For starters I have +1'ed all your questions(4). And also can you paste the code that you tried after my suggestions/changes. I will try to analyse that and help you.

Comment: did you get it working? I just made it work. Let me know and I will show you how...

Comment: @user1186061 : It worked for me when I made the chagnes in the answer that I have given. But it did not work out for you. So, I would love to see how you made it work.

Comment: Ok, what happened was the server was waiting for the phone to send a "socket.shutdownOutput()" in order to close the inputBuffer and transmit the result from the server to the phone, here is the code:                                      out.write(givenIndex.getBytes());
   while ((count = bis.read(bytes)) > 0) {
    out.write(bytes, 0, count);
   }

   out.flush();
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
     socket.getInputStream()));
   in.ready();
   socket.shutdownOutput();

   String userInput = in.readLine();
   long result = Long.valueOf(userInput).longValue();